# Multiple picker input are not working properly in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm just a beginner at react native and I was try to make something for my practice purpose. I'm making a eCommerce kind app, and using react-native-modal-filter-picker to get quantity.

But, When I update value of one product, Value of all products are automatically updating itself.

I think because of I'm calling the similar function for all the value input. But, I don't know how to pass it dynamically by id/key and update only one value. Can someone tell me how to do so.

Here I'm attaching the screenshot of my current design: [problem of updating multiple picker from any one picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfkqC.jpg)

And here is my code which I'm suffering from...:)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet,View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Dimensions, KeyboardAvoidingView,} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title, Item, Input, List, ListItem, Thumbnail, Text, } from 'native-base';
import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";
import ModalFilterPicker from 'react-native-modal-filter-picker'


let WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window');


type Props = {};
export default class Home extends Component<Props> {

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}

constructor (props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);
    this.state = {
        visible: false,
        picked: '0',
        count: '0',
    };
}

render() {

    const { visible, picked, count } = this.state;

    const options = [
        {
            key: '0',
            label: '0',
        },
        {
            key: '1',
            label: '1',
        },
        {
            key: '2',
            label: '2',
        },
        {
            key: '3',
            label: '3',
        },
        {
            key: '4',
            label: '4',
        },
        {
            key: '5',
            label: '5',
        },
        {
            key: '6',
            label: '6',
        },
        {
            key: '7',
            label: '7',
        },
        {
            key: '8',
            label: '8',
        },
        {
            key: '10',
            label: '10',
        },
        {
            key: '11',
            label: '11',
        },
    ];

    return (
                <Container>
                    <Header noShadow style={{backgroundColor: '#2e6153',}} androidStatusBarColor="#004c40">
                        <Left style={{flex: 1,}}>
                            <Button transparent hitSlop={{top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3}} style={{paddingLeft: 6,}}>
                                <Icon name='md-menu' style={{fontSize: 30,}}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Body style={{flex: 5, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'RobotoBold', color: '#fff',}}> Logo </Text>
                        </Body>
                        <Right style={{flex: 1,}}>
                            <Button transparent hitSlop={{top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3}}>
                                <Icon name='md-cart' style={{fontSize: 26,}}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <View style={{height: 55, backgroundColor: '#2e6153', paddingHorizontal: 10,}}>
                        <Item style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', marginLeft: 0, borderRadius: 5, borderBottomWidth: 0,}}>
                            <Button transparent hitSlop={{top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3}}>
                                <Icon active name="search" style={{color: '#000',}}/>
                            </Button>
                            <Input placeholder="Search" style={{height: 45,}}/>
                            <Button transparent hitSlop={{top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3}}>
                                <Icon active name="barcode" style={{color: '#000',}}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Item>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <List>
                            <ListItem thumbnail>
                                <Left>
                                    <Thumbnail square source={{ uri: 'http://shfcs.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/MedRes_Product-presentation-2.jpg' }}/>
                                </Left>
                                <Body style={{height: 80,
                                    paddingTop: 10,
                                    paddingBottom: 10,
                                }}>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={1}>Product Name</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>Sub Category</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>Category</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Body>
                                <Right>
                                    <Button bordered onPress={this.onShow} style={{width: 58,justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                                        <Text>{this.state.picked}</Text>
                                    </Button>
                                    <ModalFilterPicker
                                        visible={visible}
                                        onSelect={this.onSelect}
                                        onCancel={this.onCancel}
                                        options={options}
                                    />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem thumbnail>
                                <Left>
                                    <Thumbnail square source={{ uri: 'http://shfcs.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/MedRes_Product-presentation-2.jpg' }}/>
                                </Left>
                                <Body style={{height: 80,
                                    paddingTop: 10,
                                    paddingBottom: 10,
                                }}>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={1}>1839 Blue Box 100 FSC ACE</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>Cig-SubGeneric</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>CIGARETTES</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Body>
                                <Right>
                                    <Button bordered onPress={this.onShow} style={{width: 58, justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                                        <Text>{this.state.picked}</Text>
                                    </Button>
                                    <ModalFilterPicker
                                        visible={visible}
                                        onSelect={this.onSelect}
                                        onCancel={this.onCancel}
                                        options={options}
                                    />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem thumbnail>
                                <Left>
                                    <Thumbnail square source={{ uri: 'http://shfcs.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/MedRes_Product-presentation-2.jpg' }}/>
                                </Left>
                                <Body style={{height: 80,
                                    paddingTop: 10,
                                    paddingBottom: 10,
                                }}>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={1}>1839 Blue Box 100 FSC ACE</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>Cig-SubGeneric</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                                <Text note>CIGARETTES</Text>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Body>
                                <Right>
                                    <Button bordered onPress={this.onShow} style={{width: 58,justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                                        <Text>{this.state.picked}</Text>
                                    </Button>
                                    <ModalFilterPicker
                                        visible={visible}
                                        onSelect={this.onSelect}
                                        onCancel={this.onCancel}
                                        options={options}
                                    />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                    </View>
                </Container>
    );
}
  onShow = () => {
this.setState({ visible: true });
}

onSelect = (picked) => {
this.setState({
  count: picked,
  picked: picked,
  visible: false
})
 }

 onCancel = () => {
this.setState({
  visible: false
});
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    // backgroundColor: '#00796b',
},

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being caused because each listitem is referencing the same variable. `this.state.visible`. There's a few ways that you solve this, the simplest would be to use multipe `this.state.visible`.

```
this.state = {
    visible1: false,
    visible2: false,
    visible2: false,
    picked: '0',
    count: '0',
};
```

And for the onPress, use `onPress={() => this.setState({visible$: true})}`. Replacing $ with the appropriate number.

And make sure that each listitem is referencing it's own `this.state.visible`.

Comment: I tried this but nothing is happening...
Can you tell me any another solution please...